# Web application to manage data (podio alternative)

Tags: web-apps, database, gui, api, crm

What I need is a recommendation, for an out of the box database with a UI on top.
Necessary features:

- A database change log: every time an item changes, I need to be able to see what has changed.
- A UI on top, such that users can interact with the data.
- Webhooks
- An API interface such that I can code custom functionality up against the database.
- File storage: Attach files to database entries.

Nice to have:

- Zapier integration
- User roles: Let certain users access different levels of data.
- Tasks: We can attach certain tasks to certain items and hence use the system as a kind of CRM system as well.

Currently we are using podio, where there are a few things, we really like:

- Database change log.
- UI: Although limited in scope of access control stil ok.
- Calculated fields: Podio will runningly do calculations to fill in fields. Example could be a contract that contains x items. A calculation field in the contract item, could be to sum up a value from these items. This is also our biggest pain points, because calculation fields stalls or never calculates, until we force them.

We're switching from podio, because it seems like it's a dying platform. Support are in rapid decay, and new features / bug fixes are non-existant.

Any recommendations?

For context: We're a startup with limited funds and a rapid growth. We don't want the biggest solutions, and we want flexibility, without having to build the solution our selves.